# pg_restore --clean not working because cascade drop

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm working with a copy (`DB-B`) of a database (`DB-A`) I keep up to date by running daily:

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d someDB --clean -j 2 -L WhatToImportList admin.dump
```

But I started noticing duplicate records in `DB-B` tables. Upon further investigation seems the `--clean` is not dropping the tables in `DB-B` because it would require a cascade drop on other tables and views that are in my `DB-B` but NOT in the origin `DB-A`.

1. Is it possible to force the import of data WITHOUT doing a cascade drop? I want to keep all my custom tables, views and functions!
2. If not, what would be a good duplication strategy where I import the data from `DB-A` to `DB-B` but keep all my functions, views and tables I need for my analysis in `DB-B`?

Thanks.

Edit: possible work around: truncating each table and then importing them... but i'd have to include in the script EACH TABLE.

Edit2:
To help future readers, with this managed to generate a list of all the tables that had to be truncated:

```
SELECT 'TRUNCATE ' || table_name || ';'
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema='my_schema'
   AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
```

Comment: I cannot think of a better way either.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , if YOU do not know other way, is because there is NO other way! (when using pg_restore, that is). Thanks for checking my post.